# same action type for combined reducers

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm new to React, just a question on Reducers. Below is some example code from a book:

```
export default createStore(combineReducers(
{
    modelData: ReducerOne,
    stateData: ReducerTwo
 }));
```

And the book says:

**Each reducer operates on a separate part of the data store, but when an action is processed, each reducer is passed the action until one of them returns a new data store object, indicating that the action has been processed.**

Below is my questions:

Q1. Let's say there is action and the action type is called "Update",  only ReducerTwo handle this action type. Does it mean that ReducerOne will still be called first then ReducerTwo gets called after? if yes,this is inefficient, isn't it? Image there is a lot of reducers, most of them who don't handle the relevant type will be called until the correct reducer is called?

Q2. Does it mean that the action types have to be unique in all reducers? For example, ReducerTwo handle "Update" actiont type, so ReducerOne cannot handle "Update" , and we have to modify the name to something like "Update_One"? And each time we add a new reducer, we need to check all existing reducers to see if there will be duplicated name of action types, which is a tedious and error-prone process?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a reducer:

```
export default (state=INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case CRUD_CREATE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: 'Registro creado correctamente.',
        showMessage: true,
        currentPage: 0,
        selectedItem: null
      }
    }
    case CRUD_DELETE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: 'Registro eliminado correctamente.',
        showMessage: true,
        currentPage: 0,
        selectedItem: null
      }
    }
    case CRUD_UPDATE_SUCCESS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        alertMessage: 'Registro actualizado correctamente.',
        showMessage: true,
      }
    }
  }
};
```

And all of them have exactly the same format.

As you can see, there is no way to know which one addresses each action. So it basically follows a [chain of responsibility pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/chain-of-responsibility).